# Classical Greek for 'You came home to our hearts with your shield'?

Tags: sentence-translation

Sorry I know this is Latin. but I was hoping to find some dual classicists on here.

Could anyone provide me with a classical Greek translation of the sentence:

"You came home to our hearts with your shield."

I was hoping to get there myself, I have:

ἐπανῆλθες εἰς τὴν οἰκείαν.

For "you came home"

and "άμα σῇ ᾰ̓σπῐ́δῐ"

For with your shield, but the complexity is now defeating me - I would be very glad is someone could help me.

(Once again sorry to trouble the Latin site.)

Comment: No need to apologize! This site covers Ancient Greek as well as Latin (and also Etruscan, Oscan, Punic, Aramaic, and more).

Comment: That said, do you mean "with" in the sense of "by means of", or "with" in the sense of "accompanied by"? I'm guessing the latter, but something like "you came home by using your shield [instead of your sword]" will be different from "you came home holding your shield"

Comment: Hello - thank you for your reply, and your welcome. I do mean in the sense of accompanied with.

Comment: @Draconis "This site covers Ancient Greek": Does it? Wink wink. If it does, I can finally change my username!!!

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal [It certainly seems so!](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/policy-on-greek-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "You came home…"

<s>I would use *ἥκεις* for this; it's technically a present-tense verb, but it generally has a perfect meaning, "you have come back". If you want to be emphatic, add *πάλιν*, "…back again".</s>

EDIT: Brianpck in the comments suggested an even better verb, *ἐνοστήσας*, "you came back home". I'd recommend this one instead of my original suggestion. It comes from the word *νόστος* "journey home", as made famous in the *Odyssey*, and the root of "nostalgia".

> "…to our hearts…"

I'd leave off "our" and just go with *εἰς τὰς καρδίας*; the definite article can give that sense on its own. If you want to include the "our", that's *ἐις τὰς **ἡμετέρας** καρδίας*.

> "…with your shield."

Nice and straightforward, *σὺν τῇ ασπίδι*. Once again, leaving off the non-emphatic "your".

All in all, ***ἐνοστήσας σὺν τῇ ασπίδι ἐις τὰς ἡμετέρας καρδίας***. You can reorder the words pretty freely in order to get the effect you want, too.

Note: I'm not entirely certain about using *σύν* like this. I might instead use a participle, something like "…holding your shield". But that's somewhat of a change in meaning.

Comment: νοστέω is also a great choice for "come home."

Comment: @brianpck Oh, of course! I don't know how I missed that one!

Comment: It's worth noting that ἥκεις may or may not reflect the OP's intended meaning, since it implies "you have come and are still here". Also, I'd leave in "our" in this case because it isn't clearly implied by the context (could be someone else's hearts).

Comment: @TKR Fair; added a note on that.

Comment: (On the edit, it should surely be ἐνοστήσας, unless we're being Homeric.)

Comment: @TKR In fairness, *nostein* is a fairly epic verb…but no, that was totally just my mistake. I haven't had to conjugate Greek verbs in far too long! Fixed.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your input - it has all been very valuable, and a good learning experience.